# Mover objetos SVG

Tags: javascript

Tenho 3 objetos do tipo SVG rect. Quero move-los com o rato. O problema é que so consigo mover quando crio o objeto dinamicamente no codigo JavaScript. Se crio no HTML dentro do SVG, não consigo mover. Exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/hL3wpup5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu código só está a adicionar um event handler ao elemento `circle`, tens de adaptar para os elementos `rect` também.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var rects = document.querySelectorAll('rect');
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    rects[i].addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
}
shape.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
```

(ou podias usar delegação como no exemplo no final da resposta)

Depois tens de resolver outro problema, as cooredenadas. No *setter* e no *getter* uma vez que elementos `rect` tem `x` e `y`, mas elementos `circle` têm `cx`  e `cy`.

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
function mousedown(evt) {
    var evt = evt || window.event;
    ddData.element = this;
    ddData.initialX = evt.clientX;
    ddData.initialY = evt.clientY;
    ddData.originalX = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, this.tagName == 'rect' ? 'x' : 'cx'));
    ddData.originalY = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, this.tagName == 'rect' ? 'y' : "cy"));
};

svg.onmousemove = function (evt) {
    var evt = evt || window.event;
    var el = ddData.element;
    if (el) {
        var posX = ddData.originalX + evt.clientX - ddData.initialX;
        var posY = ddData.originalY + evt.clientY - ddData.initialY;
        if (el.tagName == 'rect') {
            //move object
            el.setAttributeNS(null, "x", posX);
            el.setAttributeNS(null, "y", posY);
        } else {
            el.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", posX);
            el.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", posY);
        }
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y2d5og5s/

Podes mesmo fazer isto com delegação (via `event.target`) e assim nem precisas do ciclo `for`. Neste exemplo em baixo uso `.id` para decidir se o elemento pode ser movido ou não (assumindo que elementos com ID podem ser movidos), mas podias fazer isso com uma classe ou `data-` field.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g50L96e7/

Comment: Obrigado. Isso move todos os objetos svg, até o fundo que também são rect. Como posso limitar isso? So mover os pequenos rect.

Comment: @akm tens várias opções, vou juntar exemplo daqui a uma hora quando estiver no computador de novo. Mas podes adicionar classe e verificar isso, ou um data- field, ou limitar o for para i = 2.

Comment: @akm: http://jsfiddle.net/g50L96e7/ - mudei mais um pouco, usando delegação. Assim não precisas do ciclo for.

Comment: Estou tentando obter as coordenadas do objecto, quando é mudado de posição com o var x = this.getAttributeNS(null, "x"); mas o valor me da null. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/g50L96e7/1/

Comment: @akm isso é porque o `this` nesse handler é o `svg`, tens de usar `event.target` -> http://jsfiddle.net/g50L96e7/2/

Comment: Como posso guardar as posiçoes dos objetos que nao estou a mover?

Comment: @akm nesse caso sugiro que tenhas um objeto onde guardas isso. Faz uma pergunta nova sobre isso. É bem util ao site ter uma questão dessas.