# Mover imagem png

Tags: javascript, svg

Consigo mover um objeto SVG com o rato em JavaScript, queria agora mover uma imagem do tipo png ou svg.

```
<svg>
  <image xlink:href=image.png x=0 y=0 height=20 width=20 />
</svg>
```

Codigo funcional ao mover objetos svg: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xq618tgs/

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Consigo mover o rectangulo vermelho mas não consigo mover uma imagem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kpvgkrey/

Comment: é possivel trocar um png por um formato svg @Sergio? So alterar o caminho da imagem?

Comment: @akm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ta feito, observe comentários.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

//create rect
var shape = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");

svg.appendChild(shape);
svg.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

var ddData = {
  element: null,
  initialX: 0,
  initialY: 0,
  originalX: 0,
  originalY: 0
};

//start move 
function mousedown(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  ddData.element = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (!ddData.element.id) return ddData.element = null;
  ddData.initialX = evt.clientX;
  ddData.initialY = evt.clientY;
  // adicionei verificação de tag image, com o mesmo tratamento do retangulo.
  ddData.originalX = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, ddData.element.tagName == 'rect' || ddData.element.tagName == 'image' ? 'x' : 'cx'));
  ddData.originalY = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, ddData.element.tagName == 'rect' || ddData.element.tagName == 'image' ? 'y' : "cy"));
};


svg.onmousemove = function(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  var el = ddData.element;
  if (el) {
    var posX = ddData.originalX + evt.clientX - ddData.initialX;
    var posY = ddData.originalY + evt.clientY - ddData.initialY;
    // adicionei verificação de tag image, com o mesmo tratamento do retangulo.
    if (el.tagName == 'rect' || el.tagName == 'image') {
      //move object
      el.setAttributeNS(null, "x", posX);
      el.setAttributeNS(null, "y", posY);
    } else {
      el.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", posX);
      el.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", posY);
    }
  }
}

//stops drag movement
svg.onmouseup = function(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  ddData.element = null;
}
```

```html
<svg width="90%" height=500px>
  <rect id=1 ry=0 rx=0 x=50 y=50 width=20px height=20px fill=red />
  <!-- adicionei um id -->
  <image id=2 xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM8xJ.png' x=0 y=0 height=20 width=20 />
  <svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Esta pergunta é parecida com outras que já fizeste. Mudaste pequenos detalhes que deviam fazer parte da pergunta original.

O problema neste código é que estás a usar `image` e já não `circle` como tinhas antes. Assim como ambos `rect` e `image` usam coordenadas `x|y` a verificação `ddData.element.tagName == 'rect' ? 'x' : 'cx')` deixa de estar certa. Deves mudar para `ddData.element.tagName != 'circle'`.

[Na outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53908/129) tinhas também IDs nos elementos que querias mover, daí que tinhas a linha de código `if (!ddData.element.id) return ddData.element = null;` que agora já não faz sentido.

Corrigindo essas linhas o resultado é: http://jsfiddle.net/kpvgkrey/